# ListBox with hyperlink -> selection changed

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, selecteditem

I want to do with xaml bindings such feature:

Listbox contains hyperlinks.

When hyperlink clicked - we go to another frame

But also SelectedItem must changed, and on another frame we show info about selected item.

I want it without subscribing click/selected events. Only declarative

Example of my listbox

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1" 
        x:Name="OrderTypesListBox"          
        ItemsSource="{Binding OrderTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCall.OrderType, Mode=TwoWay}"            
    >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="/WindowPage" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="WindowPage"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now solve like that

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" 
        x:Name="OrderTypesListBox"          
        ItemsSource="{Binding OrderTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCall.OrderType, Mode=TwoWay}"            
    >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <HyperlinkButton                            
                    TargetName="ContentFrame" 
                    NavigateUri="{Binding OrderTypeNextPage}"                           
                    Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"
                    Tag="{Binding}"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OrderTypesListBox.SelectedItem = (sender as HyperlinkButton).Tag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a HyperlinkButton. Perform the needed actions when the SelectedItem changes in your ViewModel.

**Edit:** If you need to respond to all click events even if the item is already selected then you can use a Behavior to do this. Just create a behavior for the TextBlock that navigates on the TextBlock click event.

**Edit2:** Behaviors are pretty simple to code up and easy to use (and don't break the MVVM paradigm).

```
public class NavigatingTextBlockBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
    AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseDown);
  }

  private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WindowPage"));
  }
}
```

Comment: If item already selected - i cannot do this without click += - selected not changed when user clicked already selected item.

Comment: You can use a behavior to do this then.

Comment: Some example of Behaviors will be very helpfull.

Comment: Not useful for me... To much code - i have frame on main page and navigating frames into that page - NavigationService not worked for me. And also i will generate links by binding on different items. I think that change selecteditem on hyperlink.click+= will be simple than behaviors

Comment: Too much code? Sounds like you're looking for a solution that doesn't exist. If you want help with your frames then you have to post some information about it.

Comment: No. I simply want declarative solution. Without complex, non-intuitive backend jn c#. And if this does not exists - i want code to be simple as possible